# How to find all integer solutions of an equation which are divisible by 8?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have to find out all integer solutions of $n^2+15$ which are divisible by 8. So my idea was to solve the following equation.

$$n^2+15=8\cdot k \to n^2=8\cdot k-15 \to  n=\sqrt{8\cdot k-15}$$

But this doesn't work.I tried some numbers $n=1, n=3, n=5, n=7$ for these numbers I get integer solutions of $n^2+15$ which are divisible by 8. It seems to be that $n$ must be odd. How do I solve this correctly?

Best regards

Comment: For future questions use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

It's very simple with congruences mod. $8$:
$$n^2+15\equiv 0\mod8\iff n^2\equiv 1\mod 8.$$
Now calculate the squares of the units mod.8, which are
$$\{\pm 1,\pm 3\}.$$

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer but can you explain me why n2+15≡0mod8 and n2≡1mod8 are equivalent? We started recently with modular arithmetic

Answer (score 2):

HINT: I would suggest using modularity (mod 8).

$n^2 + 15 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$.

From there, that is the same as $n^2 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$.

So, $(n+1)(n-1) \equiv 0 \pmod 8$.

Obviously, $n$ can't be even, because then $n+1$ and $n-1$ would be odd, in which case the product $(n+1)(n-1)$ would then be odd, and never $\equiv 0 \pmod 8$.

Can you see where to go from there?

Answer (score 0):

$n^2 + 15 = 8k \implies$

$n^2 -1 = 8(k-2) \implies$

$(n + 1)(n-1) = 8(k-2)$

If $n$ is even then $n+1$ and $n-1$ are odd and this is impossible.

If $n$ is odd then $n+1$ and $n-1$ are even.  If one of them is not divisible by $4$ than the other one is.  So if $n$ is odd hen $(n+1)(n-1)=n^2 -1$ is divisible by $8$ and $n^2 +15$ is divisible by $8$.

..or ..

Postactively:  If $n = 2k+1$ than $n^2 + 15 = (2k+1)^2 + 4k^2 + 4k + 16 = 4(k^2 + k + 2)= 8(\frac {k(k+1) }2 + 1)$

... or ...

Let $n = 4k + i; i = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2$

Then $n^2 + 15 = 16k + 8ki + i^2 + 15$ so $n^2 + 15$ is divisible by $8$ iff $15+i^2$ is.  $15+ 0^2$ and 15+ (\pm 2)^2$ are not.  $15 + (\pm 1)^2 = 16$ is.

So $n^2 + 15$ is divisible by $8$ iff $n \equiv \pm 1 \mod 4$ iff $n$ is odd.